# AndroidX Room generated class error: "Class is public, should be declared in a file named class.java"

Tags: android, android-room, androidx

Numerous similar questions on SO but they do not pertain to classes generated by the AndroidX Room library. Please do not mark this question a duplicate, because similar questions relate to traditional Java classes, not those generated by Room.

Following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) on Android Room, I have defined a database and table entity as follows:

Database:

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    ...
)
```

But upon building, I receive an error traced to a generated file `user.java`:

`error: class User is public, should be declared in a file named User.java`

Has anyone run into this error when working with Room?

Comment: Is your data class in its own file?

Comment: I've declared the data class inside an `entities.kt` file

Comment: What Room libraries (and versions) do you have in your Gradle file?

Comment: Room Version 2.2.5 for `room-runtime`, `room-common`, and `room-compile`

Comment: Try moving it to its own file named User.kt.

Comment: That solved it for me! Feel free to provide as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you got a workaround, guessing here but maybe adding the Room ktx extension in Gradle too could help here? It sounds like a Room bug with Kotlin.

Comment: Could also try a more recent version of Room. Current is 2.4.2

Comment: Reverting the filename and truing with the current version of Room did not resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the entity to its own file named `User.kt`.